# floating submenu in sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a left sidebar,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Kendozone </title>
    <!-- Global stylesheets -->
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.kendozone.com/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css">

    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.kendozone.com/css/app.css">

        </head>

<body class="sidebar-xs  has-detached-right navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://my.kendozone.com"><img src="/images/logored.png" alt=""></a> <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs-block mt-15"> <li class="dropdown language-switch-mobile"> <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-second-toggle"> <a class="dropdown-toggle pl-20 pr-20 " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">  <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" class="position-left" alt="">  </a> <ul class="dropdown-menu"> <li><a class="mexico" href="https://my.kendozone.com/lang/es"> <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" alt="Español"> Español</a></li> <li><a class="english" href="https://my.kendozone.com/lang/en"> <img src="/images/flags/GB.png" alt="English"> English</a></li> </ul> </a> </li> <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-second-toggle"> <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1IZ2nbY2o40/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHEY/KrhjLc7m66g/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="kendozone_avatar"> </a> </li> <li> <a class="sidebar-mobile-main-toggle"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify3 mobile-menu"></i></a> </li> </ul> </div> <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-second-toggle"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav breadcrumbs">  <ol class="breadcrumb">   <li class="active">Panel de control</li>   </ol>   </ul> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <li class="dropdown language-switch-desktop"> <a class="dropdown-toggle pl-20 pr-20 " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">  <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" class="position-left" alt="">  </a> <ul class="dropdown-menu"> <li><a class="mexico" href="https://my.kendozone.com/lang/es"> <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" alt="Español"> Español</a></li> <li><a class="english" href="https://my.kendozone.com/lang/en"> <img src="/images/flags/GB.png" alt="English"> English</a></li> </ul> </li> <li class="dropdown dropdown-user"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdown-user"> <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1IZ2nbY2o40/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHEY/KrhjLc7m66g/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="kendozone_avatar"> <span>Julio</span> </a> <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"> <li><a href="https://my.kendozone.com/users/flordcactusatgmail-com/edit "><i class="icon-user"></i> Perfil</a></li>  <li > <a class="protip" data-pt-title="Torneos eliminados" href="https://my.kendozone.com/tournaments/deleted"><i class="icon-trash-alt position-left sidemenu"></i><span>Torneos eliminados</span> </a> </li>   <li><a href="https://my.kendozone.com/logs"> <i class="icon-file-text"></i> Logs </a> </li> <li><a href="https://my.kendozone.com/auth/oauth"> <i class="icon-lock5"></i>Tokens </a> </li>  <li class="divider"></li> <li><a href="https://my.kendozone.com/logout" id="logout"><i class="icon-switch2"></i> Desconectar </a> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> </div> </div><!-- Page container -->
<div class="page-container">

    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="page-content">
            <div class="sidebar sidebar-main sidebar-fixed"> <div class="sidebar-content"> <div class="anchor-top"> <ul class="navigation navigation-main"> <li class=active> <a href="https://my.kendozone.com" class="protip" data-pt-title="Dashboard"> <i class="icon-display4 position-left sidemenu" title data-original-title="Main"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a> </li> <li > <a class="protip" data-pt-title="Federaciones" href="https://my.kendozone.com/federations"> <i class="icon-address-book position-left sidemenu"></i><span>Federaciones</span> </a>  <li > <a class="protip" data-pt-title="Torneos creados" href="https://my.kendozone.com/tournaments"><i class="icon-trophy2 position-left sidemenu"></i><span>Torneos creados</span> </a> </li> <li > <a class="protip" data-pt-title="Participaciones" href="https://my.kendozone.com/users/flordcactusatgmail-com/tournaments"> <i class="icon-medal2 position-left sidemenu"></i><span>Participaciones</span> </a> </li>  <li > <a class="protip" data-pt-title="Invitations" href="https://my.kendozone.com/invites"><i class="icon-envelop3 position-left sidemenu"></i><span>Invitations</span> </a> </li>  </ul> </div> <div class="anchor-bottom"> <ul class="navigation navigation-main"> <li class="navigation-bottom"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">  <img src="/images/flags/MX.png" class="side_flag" alt="">  </a> </li> <li class="side_avatar"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"> <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1IZ2nbY2o40/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHEY/KrhjLc7m66g/photo.jpg?sz=50" alt="kendozone_avatar" class="side_avatar"> </a> <ul class="onclick-menu-content"> </ul> </li> </ul> </div> </div> </div>    
    <!-- Main content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">


            <!-- Content area -->

            <div class="content"></div>                 

            <!-- /content area -->

        </div>
        <!-- /main content -->

    </div>
    <!-- /page content -->

</div>
<!-- /page container -->

<script src="https://my.kendozone.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>

</script>
<script src="https://my.kendozone.com/js/app.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.protip();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to have a submenu on the 2 last icon, but submenu want to open at the bottom of the sidebar...

Is there a way to open submenu when clicked, and open it floating right???

I would like to open a submenu "protip like".

Basically, I want to transfer profile ( Julio ) and flags that actually are in top bar in the bottom of the sidebar.

Comment: Can you put a working example in a snippet? Right now your code doesn't show anything. I don't think many people are going to want to download a zip.

Comment: Did it ! You have to open it in full screen to see dark side bar